# OpenMP c++ threads call fortran routines to process data

Tags: c++, fortran, openmp

I have created a C++ class to wrap a huge/un-readable fortran code. This code does not contain common blocks or modules, but it has some save statements and equivalence statements. The idea is that the class contains members that are sent to these fortran routines to store temporary results.

I have tested this C++ class with single-threaded MPI processes and it works nicely. But if I try a OpenMP parallelization, it looks like inside the fortran code, threads start to tamper with each others variables, especially inside loops. The way I have implemented the parallel part, is that I have created an vector of objects so each thread uses its own object from that vector.

I have spent some time reading on the net and it seems that defining the fortran functions/subroutines as recursive could help. I have done so, but I still get the error "Fortran runtime error: Loop variable has been modified".

Here is a simplified version of the wrapper:

```
int nthreads = 16;
vector<clte*> lte;
lte.resize(nthreads);
for(auto &it:lte) it = new clte(input);

#pragma omp parallel default(shared) private(xx,yy,tt,tid,ele,ele1,ele2,ele3,kk) num_threads(nthreads)  
{
  tid = omp_get_thread_num();
  for(tt = 0; tt < nt; tt++){
    for(yy = 0; yy< ny; yy++){
#pragma omp for schedule(dynamic,2)
      for(xx = 0; xx < nx; xx++){
         /* --- Compute array offsets ---*/
         ele =  tt*ny*nx*nw*4 + yy*nx*nw*4 + xx*nw*4;
         ele1 = tt*ny*nx*ndep + yy*nx*ndep + xx*ndep;
         ele2 = tid*ndep;
         ele3 = tt*ny*nx*6*ndep*4*nw + yy*nx*6*ndep*nw*4 + xx*6*ndep*nw*4;

         /* --- synthesize spectra and gradient---*/
         synthOneGrad(lte[tid], nw, ndep, m[tid], dpar,  &res[ele], &grad[ele3]);
   }// xx
  } //yy
 } // tt
} // pragma
```

Inside synthOneGrad, each thread will call a method lte->eos, that calls the fortran functions.

Is there a way to force each openMP thread to use their own private memory inside the fortran routines. I am confident that the C++ part must be ok, but it is the fortran routines that mess up with the variables.

Comment: OpenMP threadprivate makes sense here.

Comment: Thanks, but I thought that threadprivate does not work with variables that are defined inside other subroutines, or am I wrong?

Comment: I think the problem is the SAVE statements in the fortran module, perhaps looking in each subroutine and making those threadprivate would help?